# Invoice package add total amount to total row

Tags: invoice

I'm using the [invoice package](https://ctan.org/pkg/invoice) to write my invoices at the moment. I'm a freelancer so each \Fee is some task I did, and the count refers to the amount of hours I spent on the task. For example:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\address{...}
\signature{...}
\date{...}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{...}
    \opening{Invoice XX 2023}
    \begin{invoice}{Dollar}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{My Project}%
      \Fee{Task 1} {60} {2}
      \Fee{Task 2} {60} {5}
      \Fee{Task 3} {60} {4}
    \end{invoice}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to add the total amount of hours (i.e. the total count) to the Amount summations and total? So for the example above it would display 11 total next to the 660 total amount?

Answer (score 0):

`Invoice` package does not sum `Count` values, thus you should modify some internal commands of the package.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\address{...}
\signature{...}
\date{...}
    
\newcounter{Count}  <---------- Declare counter

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Fee@Line}[3]{%
    \gdef\Flag{3}%
    #1          &   &#2 &#3 &
        \FPmul\r{100}{#2}% added 2006-01-04
        \setcounter{One@Fee}{1 *\real{\r} * \real{#3} }%
        \addtocounter{ST@Fee}{\theOne@Fee}%
        \addtocounter{Fee}{\theOne@Fee}%
        \addtocounter{Fee@ctr}{1}%
        \addtocounter{Count}{#3}%     <-------- Add value to counter
        \Print@Value{\theOne@Fee}\\%
}
\renewcommand{\Tot@l}{%
    \\\hline
    \ifnum\theFee>0 \SumFees&   &   &%
                \theCount &%             <-------- Print the sum of Count field
                \Print@Value{\theFee}\\ 
        \ifVATnonzero%
            \Total@VAT@Printout%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \ifnum\theExpenses>0 \SumExpenses&  &   & &%
                \Print@Value{\theExpenses}\\ 
    \fi%
    \ifnum\theDiscount<0 \Discount@Contents&    &   &   &%
                \Print@Value{\theDiscount}\\ 
    \fi%
    \hline\hline
    \textbf{\Total} &   &   &%
        \theCount &%                     <-------- Print the sum of Count field
        \message{^^J\Currency: \BC}%
        \message{^^J\VAT: \VAT@rate}%
        \addtocounter{Total}{\theFee}%
        \message{^^J\SumFees: }\Message@Value{\theFee}%
        \addtocounter{Total}{\theVAT}%
        \message{^^J\SumVAT: }\Message@Value{\theVAT}%
        \addtocounter{Total}{\theExpenses}%
        \message{^^J\SumExpenses: }\Message@Value{\theExpenses}%
        \ifnum\theDiscount<0 %
        \addtocounter{Total}{\theDiscount}%
        \message{^^J\Discount@Contents: }\Message@Value{\theDiscount}%
        \fi %
        \textbf{\Print@Value{\theTotal}}%
        \message{^^J\Total: }%
            \Message@Value{\theTotal}\message{^^J^^J}\\%
    \end{longtable}
    \gdef\Flag{8}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{...}
    \opening{Invoice XX 2023}
    \begin{invoice}{Dollar}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{My Project}%
      \Fee{Task 1} {60} {2}
      \Fee{Task 2} {60} {5}
      \Fee{Task 3} {60} {4}
    \end{invoice}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]